# DDD Итоговая согласованность между агрегатами

Tags: c#, события, ddd

**Ситуация:** есть следующие агрегаты:

- Машина
- Двигатель
- Колеса
- Кузов
- Модель машины
- Модель двигателя
- Модель колес
- Модель кузова

Каждый агрегат имеет собственный идентификатор. Внутри машины расположены идентификаторы двигателя, колес и кузова.
В каждом агрегате техники располагается идентификатор соответствующей модели.

**Есть правило:** при установке в машину двигателя, колес и кузова их модели должны быть совместимы с моделью машины. Т. е. некоторые параметры моделей дочернего оборудования должны совпадать с соответствующими параметрами модели машины.

Допустим в машине уже установлен двигатель. Я решил поменять модель двигателя. Агрегат Двигатель изменился и был сохранен в базу данных. Но модель двигателя должна быть совместима с моделью машины. Получается должна быть итоговая согласованность (**Eventual Consistency**) между агрегатами Машина и Двигатель.

**Вопрос:** Как грамотно реализовать разрешение конфликта несоответствия новой модели двигателя и моделью машины, на которую двигатель уже был установлен?

**P.S.** Проще всего подобные проверки проводить заранее в прикладной службе до изменения модели агрегата. Однако в прикладных службах не должно быть логики доменной модели.

Comment: Каждый агрегатор имеет совокупность правил или критериев (считай спецификаций) к агрегируемым сущностям. Вы добавили новый двигатель => расширяете (добавляете в спецификации) список совместимых двигателей для данной модели авто.

Comment: Вы не можете менять условную физику двигателя после его создания. Вы можете добавить новую модель и запретить к использованию старую, но не можете изменять характеристики существующей модели и принудительно вытаскивать ее из машин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В условиях известного предметного окружения я бы пошел по самому простому пути.
Двигатель знает о том, что он может использоваться в машине и при собственной попытке сохранения пересохраняет (перевалидирует) машину.

В теории, надо делать какой то сервис событий, на который подписываются все заинтересованные, но тут смотрите сами, реализация будет не очень проста и довольно неочевидна, особенно в случае циклических событий, которые друг друга начнут генерировать.

Comment: Может все-таки агрегирующий должен "уметь" определять свою совместимость с агрегируемым, а не как вы предлагаете, т.е. наоборот? Спецификации на требуемый движок должны быть "зашиты" в автомобиль, а не в двигатель.

Comment: @Bulson в идеале то оно так, но на деле двигатель может вполне быть самостоятельным агрегатом и его изменение может сделать невалидным агрегат машину. Тут нет простых решений, которые бы укладывались в DDD без диких костылей. На деле все заинтересованные должны быть перевалидированы, главный вопрос - как найти этих заинтересованных.

Comment: Bulson, я полностью согласен с Вашей точкой зрения. И её я придерживался до недавнего времени. С моей точки зрения Monk прав. Тот пример, что я привел в вопросе - самый простой. На практике  у двигателя также может быть внутри оборудование, которое является агрегатом. 
Хорошенько проанализировав предметную область я пришел к выводу, что для каждого агрегата однозначно можно определить заданное для него местоположение. Например, двигатель либо снят и лежит в помещении любого типа, либо установлен на машину. Аналогичная ситуация и для другого оборудования.

Comment: Поэтому я пришел к следующему выводу. Для изменения модели агрегата можно создать доменную службу, поскольку консистентность распространяется на несколько агрегатов. Если мне необходимо изменить модель двигателя, то на вход метода службы я подаю Двигатель (по ссылке, не по идентификатору), а также два репозитория: Хранилище моделей двигателей и Хранилище моделей машин. В таких методах доменных служб я и буду проводить проверку. При этом методы изменения моделей в классах самих сущностей я отмечу как internal, чтобы модель можно было бы изменить только через доменную службу.